# Correr dos npm start en un mismo contenedor Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

estoy aprendiendo docker en estos momentos y me encontre con un inconveniente en un proyectito que quiero implementar...
Tengo un sistema que cuenta con un backend y un frontend super simples... ambos trabajan con nodejs mi idea sería automatizar el despliegue por cada departamento que lo va a usar..

Actualmente tengo el siguiente .yml

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  departamento1:
    build:
      context: './support/'
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=departamento1
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "8080:8080"
    container_name: departamento1
  departamento2:
    build:
      context: './support/'
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=departamento2
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
      - "8081:8080"
    container_name: departamento2
```

Esto me genera los contenedores usando la carpeta support y su contendido donde tiene la carmeta backend y frontend.

en el DockerBuild tengo lo siguiente:

```
FROM custom/support:beta
RUN mkdir -p /home/support
COPY support /home/support
WORKDIR /home/support/backend
RUN cd /home/support/backend
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
WORKDIR /home/support/frontend
RUN cd /home/support/frontend
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build


EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Hasta acá todo bien salvo que.

---

..
1_ una vez que inicia el contenedor debo correr manualmente:
cd ../backend && npm start
cd ../frontend && npm start
2_Si agrego el pm2 para inicializarlos, el backend funciona bien aunque el frontend se cierra segun dice el log, es porque el puerto 3333 esta en uso, aunque si corro el comando npm start en el frontend abre a la perfección en el 3000 como esta configurado.
El punto 2 tengo en claro que sucede por el CMD que envío, el problema es que si quito el CMD.. el contenedor se inicia y se apaga.

Alguna idea como solucionar este tema?

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo... Los contenedores están pensados para que cada uno tenga su propia función única. Por poner un ejemplo, un contenedor correrá el backend y otro el frontend. Tú estás intentando hacer un sólo contenedor con ambas funciones, cuando están separadas a nivel lógico (el front muestra la app al usuario, y el back hace lo que tenga que hacer para procesar las acciones del usuario).

Segundo: *WORKDIR path/to/folder* cambiará al directorio que quieras, *CMD cd path/to/folder* no lo hará, puesto que Dockerfile no funciona como un script bash: el siguiente comando no se ejecutará en al carpeta que deseas si usas la segunda opción.

En tu caso, al estar ambos servicios en el mismo contenedor, estarás comunicándolos llamando a localhost, pero deberías hacerlo a través de redes de Docker.

Para hacer el despliegue de un modo "correcto" según las buenas prácticas, deberías tener:

1. Dockerfile para el backend, que ejecute el backend

```
FROM custom/support:beta
RUN mkdir -p /home/support/frontend
COPY support/frontend /home/support/frontend
WORKDIR /home/support/frontend
RUN npm install && npm run build

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

2. Dockerfile para el frontend, que ejecute el frontend

```
FROM custom/support:beta
RUN mkdir -p /home/support/backend
COPY support/backend /home/support/backend
WORKDIR /home/support/backend
RUN npm install && npm run build

EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

3. Docker compose, o despliegue con kubernetes, para desplegar ambos contenedores.
4. Cada aplicación (back y front) deberá comunicarse con la otra mediante el nombre del servicio y mediante redes docker, no mediante localhost.

P.D: Obviamente, tendrías que separar la lógica de "server.js" para que sean dos servicios diferentes (backend y frontend)